# Cannot login Facebook with Android Facebook SDK 4.3

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

In my Android app I use Facebook SDK 4.3. I try to login with Facebook using LoginButton. Here is my code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LoginButton btnLoginFb = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    btnLoginFb.setReadPermissions("email", "user_likes", "user_friends");
    btnLoginFb.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult result) {
            Log.i("test","success");

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.i("test","cancel");

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {


        }
    });


}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

When app runs, after click button Login, it displays Facebook Activity, which requires email and password to login. But then the Callback doesn't run into onSucess. It runs into onCancel. I don't understand what is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Just use this code with login button.

```html
loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

List < String > permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("user_photos", "email",
 "user_birthday", "public_profile", "AccessToken");
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager,
new FacebookCallback < LoginResult > () {@Override
 public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

  System.out.println("onSuccess");

  String accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken()
   .getToken();
  Log.i("accessToken", accessToken);

  GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
  loginResult.getAccessToken(),
  new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {@Override
   public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,
   GraphResponse response) {
    Log.i("LoginActivity", response.toString());
    try {
     id = object.getString("id");
     try {
      URL profile_pic = new URL(
       "http://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?type=large");
      Log.i("profile_pic",
      profile_pic + "");

     } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
     name = object.getString("name");
     email = object.getString("email");
     gender = object.getString("gender");
     birthday = object.getString("birthday");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  });
  Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
  parameters.putString("fields",
   "id,name,email,gender, birthday");
  request.setParameters(parameters);
  request.executeAsync();
 }

 @Override
 public void onCancel() {
  System.out.println("onCancel");
 }

 @Override
 public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
  System.out.println("onError");
  Log.v("LoginActivity", exception.getCause().toString());
 }
});
```

For more information just look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31327897/custom-facebook-login-button-android)