# App crashing at FacebookSdk.SdkInitialize() after integrating Facebook Android SDK 4.4.0?

Tags: android, facebook, xamarin

I have integrated the latest Facebook Android SDK 4.4.0 in my Xamarin Android app but it is crashing at this line:

```
FacebookSdk.SdkInitialize (this.ApplicationContext);
```

Could you please let me know if this is a bug in the latest Facebook Android SDK 4.4.0?

```
07-29 14:54:26.595: E/mono-rt(10768): [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallStaticVoidMethod'.
07-29 14:54:26.595: E/mono-rt(10768):   at FacebookIntegrationSample.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x00016] in c:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\FacebookIntegrationSample\FacebookIntegrationSample\MainActivity.cs:36 
07-29 14:54:26.595: E/mono-rt(10768):   at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.21-series/49a04b96/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-21/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:2380 
07-29 14:54:26.595: E/mono-rt(10768):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) object:8ee5b6e6-5b83-4c32-a791-78e06e74e8e7 (intptr,intptr,intptr)
```

I have even tried running the Sample given in the Facebook Android SDK 4.4.0 but it too is crashing at the same line:  FacebookSdk.SdkInitialize (this.ApplicationContext);

Answer (score 0):

```
FacebookSdk.SdkInitialize (this.ApplicationContext);
```

Initialize FacebookSdk in onCreate before inflecting layout.like,

```html
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       //Initialize FacebookSdk here
       FacebookSdk.SdkInitialize (this.ApplicationContext);  
  
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

for more information about facebook login check my answer here. [full fb login code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31327897/custom-facebook-login-button-android/31332928#31332928)

Comment: I already called the FacebookSdk.SdkInitialize (this.ApplicationContext); before setContentView() but its still crashing.

Comment: if you want facebook login then check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31327897/custom-facebook-login-button-android/31332928#31332928