# Unable to import Session,Request,Response,GraphUser packages in android

Tags: android, facebook

I imported latest facebook sdk in my ecllipe.When i am trying to get basic information in my app,it  does n't import respective packages of Request,Response,and Session.what i do?to import respective packages.
I tried below code but facing problem at importing respective packages.

## LoginActivity.java

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (Session.getActiveSession() == null
                || Session.getActiveSession().isClosed()) {
            Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new StatusCallback() {

                @Override
                public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                        Exception exception) {
                    System.out.println("State= " + state);

                    if (session.isOpened()) {
                        System.out.println("Token=" + session.getAccessToken());
                        Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                                new GraphUserCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                            Response response) {
                                        if (user != null) {
                                            System.out.println("User=" + user);

                                        }
                                        if (response != null) {
                                            System.out.println("Response="
                                                    + response);
                                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                                    response.toString(),
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                    if (exception != null) {
                        System.out.println("Some thing bad happened!");
                        exception.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
                resultCode, data);
        }
```

Comment: This code is works with facebook SDK 3. you can't use with SDK 4.

Answer (score 3):

It happens with you because session is removed from new android SDK 4. So you cant not use this code for getting user information.

Try to use this code. It's work successfully for me.

First Initialize FacebookSdk in onCreate before inflecting layout.

```html
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
```

```html
loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

List < String > permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("user_photos", "email",
 "user_birthday", "public_profile", "AccessToken");
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager,
new FacebookCallback < LoginResult > () {@Override
 public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

  System.out.println("onSuccess");

  String accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken()
   .getToken();
  Log.i("accessToken", accessToken);

  GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
  loginResult.getAccessToken(),
  new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {@Override
   public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,
   GraphResponse response) {
    Log.i("LoginActivity", response.toString());
    try {
     id = object.getString("id");
     try {
      URL profile_pic = new URL(
       "http://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?type=large");
      Log.i("profile_pic",
      profile_pic + "");

     } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
     String name = object.getString("name");
     String email = object.getString("email");
     String gender = object.getString("gender");
     String birthday = object.getString("birthday");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  });
  Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
  parameters.putString("fields",
   "id,name,email,gender, birthday");
  request.setParameters(parameters);
  request.executeAsync();
 }

 @Override
 public void onCancel() {
  System.out.println("onCancel");
 }

 @Override
 public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
  System.out.println("onError");
  Log.v("LoginActivity", exception.getCause().toString());
 }
});
```

Add method.

```html
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode,
Intent data) {
 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, data);
 callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, data);
}
```

Comment: If you work with customized facebook button than just look my answer here.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31327897/custom-facebook-login-button-android/31332928#31332928

Comment: ok and use  LoginManager.getInstance().logOut(); for programmatically logout.