# How to directly move to other activity after login through facebook in android without experiencing lag?

Tags: android, facebook, android-activity, sdk, lag

I am new to android development. I am trying to implement login through facebook using facebook SDK 4.0.0.
Login is successful but it stays in the same activity for a second, the button changes to Logout and then the second activity appears. I want it to directly move to second activity.
I searched for it but I couldn't figure it out.

(The viewflipper is calling next layout which is just a progress bar)

Following is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


private String name;
private String lname;
private LoginButton loginButton;
private ProfileTracker  mProfileTracker;
private CallbackManager mCallBackManager;
private AccessTokenTracker mAccessTracker;
SharedPreferences sp;
private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mCallBack = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        AccessToken atoken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
        ViewFlipper vp = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flip);
        vp.showNext();
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
    }
    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException e) {
    }
};;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    sp = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (sp.contains("username")) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, userSelect.class);
        i.putExtra("username", sp.getString("username", "noUser"));
        i.putExtra("lname", sp.getString("lastname", "nomail"));
        startActivity(i);
    }

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("email");
    mCallBackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    loginButton.registerCallback(mCallBackManager, mCallBack);
}




@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);



    if (sp.contains("username")) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, userSelect.class);
        i.putExtra("username", sp.getString("username", "noUser"));
        i.putExtra("lname", sp.getString("lastname", "nomail"));
        startActivity(i);

    }
    mCallBackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mAccessTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
       @Override
       protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldToken, AccessToken newToken) {
       }
    };
    mProfileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile newProfile) {
            if ( newProfile != null)
            {

                name = newProfile.getFirstName();
                lname = newProfile.getLastName();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, userSelect.class);
                Editor editor = sp.edit();
                editor.putString("username", name);
                editor.putString("lastname",lname );
                editor.commit();
                intent.putExtra("username", name);
                intent.putExtra("lname",lname);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        }
    };
    mAccessTracker.startTracking();
    mProfileTracker.startTracking();
}
```

}

Comment: where you able to pass username to another activity after login.? b'cus I tried and it didn't end well.please help if needed Il share my code too

Answer (score 0):

You have to call new activity in your onSuccess method. By this your activity is called only after user logged in Successfully.

```html
private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mCallBack= new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
 @Override
  public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
   AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
   Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
  
   //call new activity here.
}
```

Comment: I did a edit in above code. Still the same thing. It displays mainactivity's layout for a second and then switches to other layout.

Comment: you have do in this way because if you put it on button click than if user is not successfully login than also it allows to enter in second activity.

Comment: But my problem is the lag I am facing. It does not directly goes to second activity even if I call new activity in onSuccess. for a second , mainactivity screen stays, then new activity is called.

Comment: use custom button. Than this type of problem may not occurs. check here my answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31327897/custom-facebook-login-button-android/31332928#31332928

Comment: was there a solution for this facebook lag problem?