# Custom Facebook login button

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, fragment

How to build custom facebook login button by extending fragment class or without it.

Comment: Check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31327897/custom-facebook-login-button-android and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16314651/customize-android-facebook-login-button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this simple facebook login Library:

https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook

Here is the link to my uploaded demo for simple facebook login with custom button:
http://www.demoadda.com/demo/android/login-with-facebook_108

Its the simplest way to implement the facebook login in android application.

You can add the button like this :

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/btnFb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Login with Facebook"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

And in gradle  File you can add:

```
 compile 'com.sromku:simple-fb:4.1.1'
```

Please check.