# How to customise Android Facebook Login Button?

Tags: android, xml, facebook-android-sdk

I'm able to change the `textSize` of the Login Button:
[image] but when I do it increases more than the logo - so I need to increase the size of the logo too.

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    />
```

Any idea?

Comment: use fb login button on UI screen and hide it.. after that use your own custom design button and on its on click listnr  set fb button perform click listener ..
example link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31327897/custom-facebook-login-button-android

Answer (score 0):

Use a linear layout and in that use an image and a textview in horizontal. And make the linear layout's onclickable true